# How to retain triangle position correctly to form a arrow with a line in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw a arrow using a line and a triangle which is working fine.

Now, when I resize it , it still works fine and retains the triangle position correctly in order to form a arrow along with the line but when I try to rotate it , the arrow gets disturbed.

I have handled events to make it possible to work but I am missing something I guess.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRA8Z/67/) to the work that has been done .

Code :
`

```
    var calcArrowAngle = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var angle = 0, x, y;
        x = (x2 - x1);
        y = (y2 - y1);
        if (x === 0) {
            angle = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y > 0) ? Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI * 3 / 2;
        } else if (y === 0) {
            angle = (x > 0) ? 0 : Math.PI;
        } else {
            angle = (x < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + Math.PI :
                (y < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + (2 * Math.PI) : Math.atan(y / x);
        }
        return (angle * 180 / Math.PI + 90);
    };

var logs = document.getElementById('logs');
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selection = false;
var x1=50, y1=50, x2=150, y2=100;
var line = new fabric.Line([x1, y1, x2, y2], {
        stroke: 'blue',
        opacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        selectable: true,
    left : x1,
     top : y1
    });
  //line.setControlsVisibility({'tl' : true,'tr' : true,'bl' : true,'br' : true,'ml' : false, 'mt' : false,'mr' : false,'mb' : false,'mtr' : false});

var centerX = (line.x1 + line.x2) / 2;
var centerY = (line.y1 + line.y2) / 2;
var deltaX = line.left - centerX;
var deltaY = line.top - centerY;
  var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    left : line.left - 10/2,
    top : line.top + 10,
    fill : 'blue',
    width : 20,
    height : 20,
    angle : calcArrowAngle(x2, y2, x1, y1),
    selectable : false
  });

    canvas.add(line, triangle);
  canvas.renderAll();
  canvas.observe('object:scaling', function (e) {
    var m = canvas.getActiveObject(); 
    logs.innerHTML = m.x1 + ',' + m.y1 + ',' + m.x2 + ', ' + m.y2;
    triangle.left = line.left - 10/2;
    triangle.top = line.top + 10;
    line.width *= line.scaleX;
    line.height *= line.scaleY;
    line.scaleY = line.scaleX = 1;

  });
  canvas.observe('object:moving', function (e) {
    triangle.left = line.left - 10/2;
    triangle.top = line.top + 10;
  });
  canvas.observe('object:rotating', function (e) {
    triangle.left = line.left - 10/2;
    triangle.top = line.top + 10;
  });`
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve here. You're drawing the whole outline of the arrow, if you want to vary the thickness you will have to re-calculate all of the points. The alternative would be to draw the main part of the arrow as a single, thick line - you could then adjust the stroke width of that line according to the scaling

Comment: @JohnM please open the fiddle and resize the polyline object. You can see that the thickness is not getting maintained , you can change canvas.observe method as per your needs but it's not behaving as per expectation

Comment: Question has been updated . Please check